Azure Key Vault - get multiple secrets
Using the Azure Key Vault library in C#, I wish to get secrets from our Vault as a lookup tool.
The issue is that 1 PC can have up to 4 different entries, eg PC1-1/1/2024, PC1-2/2/2024, PC1-3/3/2024 etc.
Looking at the documentation and some google searching, I can't seem to find a way to search for multiple secrets without having to get all secrets. It is not feasible to get all secrets, as we have 30k entries and it takes roughly 20 minutes before it has retrieved them all.
Is anyone aware of how I can retrieve multiple secrets with similar names? I know I cannot use an asterix/wildcard

That seems excessive to me. Wouldn't it be better to use Key Vault to store keys and then store this information in a local database using the keys to encrypt it if you need to protect this many entities?

Unfortunately there is no way to apply a search on the keys within an Azure Key Vault. But if you know, that you need up to four keys, do you know their exact names beforehand? If yes, ask for them all and check which calls succeed and which not.

There is no other/faster way than using AsyncPageable allSecrets = client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync(); // Your design seems to be broken, what you probably can do fetch the list of keys frequently and storing it in a file or database.


Is anyone aware of how I can retrieve multiple secrets with similar names? I know I cannot use an asterisk/wildcard.

You can use the code below to retrieve multiple secrets with similar names using .NET.
Code:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var vaultUri = "https://venkat678.vault.azure.net/";
        var secretNamePrefix = "pc1";

        var secrets = await GetSecretsAsync(vaultUri, secretNamePrefix);

        foreach (var secret in secrets)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{secret.Key}: {secret.Value}");
        }
    }

    public static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetSecretsAsync(string vaultUri, string secretNamePrefix)
    {
        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

        var secrets = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        await foreach (var page in client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync().AsPages())
        {
            foreach (var secret in page.Values)
            {
                if (secret.Name.StartsWith(secretNamePrefix))
                {
                    var secretValue = await client.GetSecretAsync(secret.Name);
                    secrets.Add(secret.Name, secretValue.Value.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        return secrets;
    }
}

The above code uses which calls the GetSecretsAsync method with the URI of the key vault and a prefix of the secret names. The method retrieves secrets in pages using the ListSecretsAsync method of the SecretClient class and filters the secrets based on the specified prefix. The method returns a dictionary that maps each secret name to its value in output.
Output:
pc1-1: aNwxxxx8=
pc1-10: d8dvXkAHNxxx1bE=
pc1-100: xxxe56awwKEQbyUWXxcK7KbJn4MUCgWQ=
pc1-11: xU6PSRTOgl8rbSoWxxxAhl+y9PmfQd0=
pc1-12: 8nVVQxxxKxxhKFGAY=
pc1-13: Kd27OZ/9wxxHZ9PKooI=
pc1-14: xxxlGvZPxxxSwT20w/qVC8QL7c


